# jsonschema strip out unknown fields

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, jsonschema

Is there any way to validate a json based on a schema and strip unknown keys from the json, using jsonschema?

schema example:

```
{
  "type":"object",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema",
  "required":False,
  "properties":{
    "address": {
      "type":"object",
      "required":True,
      "properties":{
        "city": {
          "type":"string",
          "required":True
        }
    },
    "phoneNumber": {
      "type":"array",
      "required":False,
      "items":
      {
        "type":"object",
        "required":False,
        "properties":{
          "number": {
            "type":"string",
            "required":False
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

example data:

```
{
  "address":{
    "streetAddress": "1 Street",
    "city":"New York",
    "name": "Tom",
    "houseNumber":18
  },
  "phoneNumber":[
    {
      "type":"home",
      "number":"212 222 2222"
    }
  ]
}
```

So the validator should pass on the data and returns the stripped version as follows:

```
{
  "address":{
    "city":"New York",
  },
  "phoneNumber":[
    {
      "number":"212 222 2222"
    }
  ]
}
```

Cerberus does have "purge_unknown" feature, but it doesn't support JSON-Schema.

Comment: Filtering is not a function of JSON Schema.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57000651/jsonschema-filter-out-invalid-items

Comment: @gregsdennis I was wondering if I use the list of validation errors and filter out the unknown keys

Comment: You could brute force the values you want to keep by iterating over the example JSON and checking for key matches in the schema data. If there is no match, then just remove that item in the example.

Answer (score 4):

I noted that you are ok with filter out the unknown field based on validation errors. In that case, you could use `additionalProperties` field to restrict unexpected keys.

```
{
  "type":"object",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema",
  "required":false,
  "properties":{
    "address": {
      "type":"object",
      "required":true,
      "properties":{
        "city": {
          "type":"string",
          "required":true
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false,
    },
    "phoneNumber": {
      "type":"array",
      "required":false,
      "items":
      {
        "type":"object",
        "required":false,
        "properties":{
          "number": {
            "type":"string",
            "required":false
          }
        },
        "additionalProperties": false,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the validation result for the given example input:

> Message:
>   Property 'streetAddress' has not been defined and the schema does not allow additional properties.
>   Schema path:
>    #/properties/address/additionalProperties
>
> Message:
>   Property 'name' has not been defined and the schema does not allow additional properties.
>   Schema path:
>    #/properties/address/additionalProperties
>
> Message:
>   Property 'houseNumber' has not been defined and the schema does not allow additional properties.
>   Schema path:
>    #/properties/address/additionalProperties
>
> Message:
>   Property 'type' has not been defined and the schema does not allow additional properties.
>   Schema path:
>    #/properties/phoneNumber/items/additionalProperties

Comment: it seems from my experiments that there's no way to do it from the top - would be so nice to have a recursive setting for this instead of having to add it to each property that has children.